# asp.net JSON escaping output -- disable?

Tags: asp.net, json

```
Sub Application_Start()
    ' ... do stuff

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear()
End Sub
```

Then inside my controller I have:

```
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim json As String = serializer.Serialize(Quotes.ToArray).Replace("\""", "")

    Return json
```

When I set a break point on final statement I can clearly see the results are just as I expected but by the time I see it in Chrome JSON viewer it has been escaped with double quotes.

When I comment the configuration line provided above SO XML is the return type but still use JSON converter on the array the data packaged in the XML tags are as I would expect.

This is what I need, not the escaped gibberish provided.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output, the actual output, and the input.

Comment: We really need to see what @msm8bball requested in order to help.